# Design Pattern for filtering elements

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to know if exist any desing pattern for filtering elements base on some criteria (for example their UUIDS). I ended up in my code with things like this :

```
if(meetsSomeCriteria(thing))){
     doSomething()
}
```

For instance, in my code I am filtering some elements based on their id by using a map :

```
if(!mymap.containsKey(myObject.getId())){
       doSomething();
       mymap.put(myObject.getId(), myObject);
   }
```

The problem is that this kind of code everywhere in the program. I would like to know if a design pattern can help me and give some hint/examples.

Thanks !!

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Are you asking if there are libraries to do this for you, or are you asking if there is a better way to refactor your code?

Comment: I am searching for a better way to refactor my code so I can replace the if with a cleaner clode

Comment: Take a look at Guava http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com

Comment: Kinky question. How your task relates to the design patterns?

Comment: Hi, I have this kind of code repeating everywhere in my code. I was wondering if a design pattern can help me refactor my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#select%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) from apache [commons
-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). Something like:

```
Collection matches = CollectionUtils.select(collection, new Predicate() {
    public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
        // evaluate predicate
    }
});
```

Internally, it most likely just iterates over the collection and executes the predicate, but it saves your the boiler-plate code.

Comment: hey this is pretty cool, is there also a generic version of this?

Comment: There is on the release trunk for commons collections (if you go into the svn repo for it). Doesn't seem that they have made a stable/GA release of the generics version yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Intercepting-filter** is one pattern used extensively with j2ee for filtering requests/responses. You can implement something similar to that.